# (Presto)How to fix SQL for AWS Athena

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

how can i fix this sql? please help me..

I don't want add group by clause. because i don't need to select this clause.

```
and count(case when aa.date between '2022-01-01' AND cast(DATE_ADD('day', -1, date_trunc('month', date(current_date))) as varchar) then cc else null end) 
    > round(cast(date_diff('day',cast('2022-01-01' as date),DATE_ADD('day', -1, date_trunc('month', date(current_date)))) as int) * 300 /365)
```

only user_id need to group by.

query:

```
select
user_id
,count(case when aa.date between '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31' then bb else null end) as count_bb
,count(case when aa.date between '2022-01-01' AND cast(DATE_ADD('day', -1, date_trunc('month', date(current_date))) as varchar) then cc else null end) as count_cc
    from aa
    where cast(aa.date as varchar) between '2022-01-01' AND cast(DATE_ADD('day', -1, date_trunc('month', date(current_date))) as varchar)
    group by 1
    having 
    count(case when aa.date between '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31' then bb else null end) > 300
    and count(case when aa.date between '2022-01-01' AND cast(DATE_ADD('day', -1, date_trunc('month', date(current_date))) as varchar) then cc else null end) 
    > round(cast(date_diff('day',cast('2022-01-01' as date),DATE_ADD('day', -1, date_trunc('month', date(current_date)))) as int) * 300 /365)
```

error:

```
must be an aggregate expression or appear in GROUP BY clause
```

Comment: Your query works fine for me, can you please provide [mre]? Also personally I would change all `count(...)` to `count_if(...)` cause it makes query shorter and clearer.

Comment: @GuruStron thank you so much for your advice! my query will be simple!!!